# How to extract certain words and values from a text file in bash

Tags: bash

Bash newbie here trying to get a hold of things by performing some simple tasks. Say I have a text file with the following text:

```
ExperimentOne results = .5 participants: 80
ExperimentTwo results = .4 participants: 75, 4 unclear reports
```

I would like to extract the ExperimentOne and ExperimentTwo result data, or any data that has the word results in its line, so that my output is simply:

```
ExperimentOne .5
ExperimentTwo .4
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `cut` you need to set the delimiter with the option `-d`:

```bsh
$ cut -d' ' -f1,4 file
ExperimentOne .5
ExperimentTwo .4
```

Answer (score 6):

Try with `awk`:

```
awk '/results/ {print $1,$4}'
```

or

```
awk '$2=="results"{print $1,$4}'
```

Comment: thanks! Is there a way to do this with grep and cut? I tried `cat filename.txt | cut -f1,3` but this didn't work, I assume there must be a simple solution with cut.

Comment: Needs to be ```$1,$4```.

Comment: I feel like Awk is the `jquery` of U&L

Comment: @Scott, true ... the `=` would be `$3` ... @val I don't think that is a fair comparison. `jquery` is some bloat you throw on users to make your life easier while `awk` is just awesomeness ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Another solution with `sed`:

```
sed -En 's/results *= *([^ ]+).*$/\1/p' filename.txt
```

If you want to use the `grep`+ `cut` pipeline, you have to remember that `cut` assumes `TAB` as field separator if you don't specify one. So, use

```
grep "results" filename.txt | cut -d' ' -f1,4
```